# Using original record ID within trigger process

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, insert

I have table `question`

```
id        int
answers   int
```

With every insert, delete call on this table I want to update `answers` column. I want to use trigger on this. I don't know how I can read `question.id` within trigger for insert, delete.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In triggers that happen after insert, you can select from the `inserted` table to get the id of any inserted rows.  Likewise for delete, you can select from the `deleted` table.

Answer (score 0):

In BEFORE/AFTER INSERT trigger you can use OLD & NEW with "id" (OLD.id/NEW.id) and "answer" (OLD.answer/NEW.answer) columns. You will able to get OLD & NEW value of each column.
Similarly in AFTER DELETE trigger you can get OLD.id & OLD.answer, which in turn will give the deleted row's values